# Why can't a literal be used as a LeftHandSideExpression in ECMAScript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

According to the ECMAScript [section 12.3](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-left-hand-side-expressions), the definition of left-hand-side expression is as follow:

```
PrimaryExpression[Yield] :
    this
    IdentifierReference[?Yield]
    Literal
    ...

MemberExpression[Yield] :
    PrimaryExpression[?Yield]
    ...

NewExpression[Yield] :
    MemberExpression[?Yield]
    ...

LeftHandSideExpression[Yield] :
    NewExpression[?Yield]
    ...
```

So, in this case, a `Literal` should be able to serve as a `LeftHandSideExpression`, such as `123 = 456`. But in practice, it can't. Can anyone explain why this doesn't work?

Comment: I'm no expert on spec reading, but isn't `123` not a `NewExpression`

Comment: @Keith If you use chain replacement (I'm not sure if I used the correct terminology), I think it is. Just like you replace a variable with its value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The spec defines some limitations which are not part of the grammar itself. Those are called "early errors". [Section 12.15.1](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/#sec-assignment-operators-static-semantics-early-errors) (ES 2019) defines early errors for assignment expressions, where it says:

> It is an early Reference Error if *LeftHandSideExpression* is neither an *ObjectLiteral* nor an *ArrayLiteral* and *AssignmentTargetType* of *LeftHandSideExpression* is invalid.

And if we look at how *AssignmentTargetType* is defined for *PrimaryExpression* in [section 12.2.1.5](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/#sec-semantics-static-semantics-assignmenttargettype):

```
12.2.1.5 Static Semantics: AssignmentTargetType
  PrimaryExpression:
    this
    Literal
    ...

   Return invalid.
```

So that's why.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I also found this regulation. I think it should be the answer but I can't assure that. Because when I try `123 = 456`, the prompt is `SyntaxError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment` which is different from `Reference Error` as mentioned in the regulation. Can you give a few words on explaining this?

Comment: I think browsers might have some leeway how they report early errors (see [16](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/#sec-error-handling-and-language-extensions)) or maybe they just implement it incorrectly. If you look at the `++` operator it also says to return a reference error, but `123++` results in a syntax error.